# how to adjust my MYSQL db when the performance different of IFNULL() vs. IS NULL

Tags: mysql, performance

How to adjust my MYSQL db?
I found the performance is very different between IFNULL() and IS NULL.

```
SELECT dtime,id FROM salesdata WHERE confirm!=1 OR confirm IS NULL ;
```

Duration/Fetch time: 0.0034 sec
'Using index condition; Using where'

```
SELECT dtime,id FROM salesdata WHERE IFNULL(confirm,0)!=1 ;
```

Duration/Fetch time: 4.680 sec

My db runs in a vm, and about ten thousand of records:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.41-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:(I add more info according to Akina's guide)

Duration/Fetch time: 0.0034 sec

'Using index condition; Using where'

vs.

Duration/Fetch time: 4.680 sec

'Using where'

It means the IFNULL() is bad performance ? Or something is wrong in my DB?

Comment: See EXPLAIN. Function kills index usage.

Comment: Thank you! I update my question :)

Comment: *It means the IFNULL() is bad performance ?* It means that you must use field-related expressions storing the field part in those state which is used in the index. If you have index `table(confirm[,...])` then you must use 1st variant - each separate condition `confirm!=1` and `confirm IS NULL` will be processed by index. Whereas `IFNULL(confirm,0)!=1` cannot. But if you'll create calculated field with the expression `IFNULL(confirm,0)` and index it, then 2nd form will be more effective because `IFNULL(confirm,0)!=1` will be processed by this index and do not need in separate conditions merge.

Comment: See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8c4f0dbca755abe71663ed12eded2c0).

Comment: I've Learned！
It is very effective!
Thank you very much！

Comment: What are the possible values of `confirm`.  (There may be a much better way to solve your problem.)

Comment: What you need to adjust is not your database but your SQL. If `IS NULL` is more efficient than `IFNULL()`, *use it!*

Comment: I know the main points of this performance issue. It is much easier to solve this trouble. Thanks for your guidance  @ Akina @ James @ user207421

Answer (score 1):

`OR` is terrible for performance -- The Optimizer can't do anything with it; it must scan the entire table (or index).

`!=` is probably terrible for a similar reason.

If `confirm` has two states, then the cleanest is

```
confirm  TINYINT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL  DEFAULT '0'
```

The set it to `1` when needed.  And use *only* these for testing:

```
WHERE confirm = 0 AND ...
WHERE confirm = 1 AND ...
```

And have composite index(es) *starting with* `confirm` when using `WHERE` clauses like those.

For your query

```
SELECT dtime,id FROM salesdata WHERE confirm = 0
```

the optimal `INDEX` would be `INDEX(confirm, dtime, id)`.  If you have other queries that test `confirm` please show them so I can recommend other indexes.  (There are multiple patterns, depending on several factors.)